# Choice sets in hypergraphs with finite edges

Tags: infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

Let $H=(V,E)$ be a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph). We say that $C\subseteq V$ is a *choice set* if $|C\cap e| = 1$ for all $e\in E$.

**Question.** Let $H=(V,E)$ be a hypergraph with $e$ finite for all $e\in E$, and suppose that for all finite sets $E_0\subseteq E$ the hypergraph $(V, E_0)$ has a choice set. Does $H$ itself necessarily have a choice set?

Comment: Right, Fedor, thanks for your answer. Is it still the same if all the members of $E$ are finite? I will modify the question accordingly. - I was hoping some compactness argument would work, but I didn't manage it. If you write down the compactness argument in an answer (or provide another answer), I'll be more than happy to accept

Comment: @FedorPetrov How is the hypergraph consisting of all infionite subsets of a countably infinite set a counterexample to the original question? If $E_0=\{e_1,e_2,e_1\cup e_2\}$ where $e_1\cap e_2=\varnothing$, then $E_0$ has no choice set. What am I missing?

Comment: Ooops. I was thinking on perfect matching instead, sorry

Comment: For a counterexample with infinite edges, consider a maximal almost disjoint family of infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ which contains an infinite collection of pairwise disjoint sets. Alternatively, consider the lines of the real projective plane.

Comment: Lines on the usual (affine) real plane also work. Or a rational plane, if you prefer countably many vertices and edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finite edges this follows indeed from compactness. Consider the Cartesian product $K=\prod e$ of all edges in Tychonoff topology. This $K$ may be understood as the set of simultaneous choices $v_e\in e$ for all edges $e$. For every pair $e\ne f$ of edges consider the open set $U(e,f)\subset K$ determined as follows: a vertex chosen in $e$ belongs to $f$. If these open sets do not cover $K$, then a choice set exists. If they do cover $K$, then finitely many of them cover $K$, that means that the choice set does not exist for finitely many edges.